# Multilingual PNP provisioning for SharePoint Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, localization, pnp-provision, spgroup

Did anybody try applying localization using PNP Provisioning for SharePoint groups? I have tried but it is not working. Can somebody please help?

````
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pnp:Provisioning xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2015/12/ProvisioningSchema">
    <pnp:Preferences Generator="OfficeDevPnP.Core, Version=2.0.1601.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <pnp:Localizations>
        <pnp:Localization LCID="1034" Name="Spanish" ResourceFile="SiteColumns-fr-FR.resx"/>
        <pnp:Localization LCID="1033" Name="English" ResourceFile="SiteColumns-En-EN.resx"/>
    </pnp:Localizations>
    <pnp:Templates ID="CONTAINER-SharePointPalsDemo">
        <pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID="SharePointPalsDemo" Version="1" xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2015/12/ProvisioningSchema">



            <pnp:SiteFields>


                <Field ID="{793F0419-9A72-48D9-B983-91BD359E5387}" Name="{resource:PNPFieldInternalName}" StaticName="MyCustomPNPField" DisplayName="{resource:PNPFieldDisplayName}" Type="Note" Required="FALSE" RichText="FALSE" Group="My Custom PNP Fields" />

            </pnp:SiteFields>

            <pnp:ContentTypes>

                <!-- Bookmark ContentTypes -->
                <pnp:ContentType ID="0x010500C562BA980E1C457B97298CA27EC2C843" Name="MyCustomContentType" Description="Test Description" Group="Custom Group">
                    <pnp:FieldRefs>
                        <pnp:FieldRef ID="793F0419-9A72-48D9-B983-91BD359E5387" Name="{resource:PNPFieldInternalName}" />
                    </pnp:FieldRefs>
                </pnp:ContentType>

            </pnp:ContentTypes>
            <pnp:Security>

                <pnp:SiteGroups>
                    <pnp:SiteGroup
                        Title="{resource:GroupName}"
                        Description="{resource:GroupName}"
                        Owner="{resource:Owner}"
                        OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership="false">
                        <pnp:Members>
                            <pnp:User Name="{resource:Owner}"></pnp:User>
                        </pnp:Members>

                    </pnp:SiteGroup>
                </pnp:SiteGroups>

                <pnp:Permissions>
                    <pnp:RoleAssignments>
                        <pnp:RoleAssignment Principal="{resource:GroupName}" RoleDefinition="Contribute">
                        </pnp:RoleAssignment>
                    </pnp:RoleAssignments>
                </pnp:Permissions>
            </pnp:Security>


        </pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
    </pnp:Templates>
</pnp:Provisioning>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried recently but a couple of years ago the only way to make it work is if your Office 365 profile languages (Delve->About me->Update profile->How can I change language and regional settings?->here->ellipsis (...)->Language and Region->My Display Languages:) are empty.  If you have a language selected then it will not populate the strings in the other languages.  I don't know whether that is still the case.

Comment: I have already changed the language and it is working for Site Columns but is not working for SharePoint Groups